# Show absolute value of determinant of a prime matrix is a perfect square.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, prime-numbers, determinant, square-numbers

Assume we have a matrix $A$ of the following form

$$ 1\leq i,j \leq n \hspace{0.5cm} A = [a_{ij}] \in M_n(\{0,1\}) \hspace{0.4cm}a_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 \hspace{0.3cm}i+j \in  \mathbb{P} \\ 0 \hspace{0.3cm} i + j \notin  \mathbb{P} \end{cases} $$

where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes the set of prime numbers. How can I prove the absolute value of its determinant is a perfect square?

---

So far, I've managed to figure out it's a symmetric matrix and has zeros on its diagonal except at $a_{11}$, which isn't much, and I haven't even made use of the prime property.

Comment: What is the determinant you get for $n=1,2,3,4$?

Comment: I get $1,-1,-1,0$ respectively.

Comment: The code I've written for it gives me $-4$ for $n = 7$.

Comment: Your determinants are in OEIS: https://oeis.org/A069191

Comment: The OEIS documentation on a linked page gives a [proof here](https://oeis.org/A069191/a069191.txt). Certainly would be nice to see it typeset properly here.

Comment: The link given by Ben is as you put it, a more general case, but https://oeis.org/A069191 seems to be what I am looking for.

Comment: @nothatcreative5 Where did you come across this fact/problem?

Comment: A freshman at my university wanted me to have a go at it, but after some time I got stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplified approach to this problem inspired by the proof presented below.

First, we consider the case where $n$ is even. Rearrange both the rows and columns of $A$ via the permutation
$$
[1,2,3,\dots,n] \mapsto [2,4,\dots,n,1,3,\dots,n-1].
$$
Rearranging the rows and columns simultaneously (i.e. applying a permutation similarity) does not affect the determinant. Because the $i,j$ row entry is zero whenever $i$ and $j$ are even, the resulting matrix has the form
$$
B = \pmatrix{0 & P\\P^\top & Q}
$$
for some matrices $P$ and $Q$ of size $n \times n$. We can rearrange the columns of this matrix (possibly changing the sign, but not the absolute value) to get the matrix
$$
C = \pmatrix{P & 0\\Q& P^\top}.
$$
Thus, we have $\det(A) = \det(B) = \pm \det(C) = \pm \det(P)\det(P^T) = \pm \det(P)^2$.

In the case where $n$ is odd, we can similarly apply the permutation
$$
[1,2,3,\dots,n] \mapsto [1,3,\dots,n-2,n,2,4,\dots,n-1].
$$
Doing so gives us a matrix of the form
$$
B = \pmatrix{
1 & 0 & x^T\\
0 & 0 & P\\
x & P^T & 0}.
$$
We note that this has the same determinant as the matrix
$$
C = \pmatrix{
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0&I&0\\
-x & 0 & I} B = 
\pmatrix{
1 & 0 & x^T\\
0 & 0 & P\\
0 & P^T & -xx^T
}.
$$
Because $C$ is block upper-triangular, we have
$$
\det(C) = 1 \cdot \det \pmatrix{0&P\\P^T & -xx^T}.
$$
By our work in the previous case, we see that the second determinant must have an absolute value equal to a perfect square.

---

This is a slight expansion of the proof presented [here](https://oeis.org/A069191/a069191.txt), which is linked to in the comments to the [OEIS sequence of these determinants here](https://oeis.org/A069191).

> **Proposition:** Let $M$ be a symmetric $n \times n$ matrix with integer coefficients (in any commutative ring) satisfying $m_{ij} = 0$ whenever $i+j$ is even, except in the case that $i=j=1$, for which we have $m_{1,1} = 1$ ($1$ can be replaced with any perfect square). Then $|\det(M)|$ is a perfect square.

*Proof:* Consider the commutative ring $A=\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and let $M_n$ be the matrix of a quadratic form on the rational field of fractions of $A$. Let $e_0,\dots,e_n$ be the vectors for the canonical basis. Let $b$ be the associated bilinear form.  By hypothesis, $b(e_i,e_j)=0$ if $i+j$ is even, except for $b(e_0,e_0)=1$.

Consider the odd case $n = 2k+1$. Let
$$
f_0=e_n\\
f_1=e_n+e_{n-2}\\
f_2=e_n+e_{n-2}+e_{n-4}\\
\vdots\\
f_k=e_n+e_{n-2}+\cdots +e_1\\
f_{k+1}=e_{n-1}\\
f_{k+2}=e_{n-1}+e_{n-3}\\
\vdots \\
f_n=e_{n-1}+e_{n-3}+\cdots +e_0.\\
$$
Then the matrix of $b$ relative to the basis $\{f_0,f_1,\dots,f_n\}$ has the form
$$
N = \pmatrix{0&P\\P^\top &Q},
$$
Where $Q$ is the matrix with a $1$ as its bottom-right entry and zeros elsewhere. Since $P$ is a square matrix, the
determinant of $N$ is $\pm$ a square (sign depending on $n \bmod 4$). Indeed, we can circularly shift the columns of $N$ repeatedly to get the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{P & 0\\Q & P^\top},
$$
which has determinant $\det(P)\det(P^\top) = \det(P)^2$. On the other hand, $N$ is obtained from $M$ via $N = X^\top MX$, where $X$ is the change of basis matrix from $\{e_0,\dots,e_n\}$ to $\{f_0,\dots,f_n\}$. Thus, we have $\det(M) = \det(N)/\det(X)^2$, which means that $\det(M)$ must also have an absolute value equal to a perfect square in $\Bbb Q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, and this determinant is a polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ which is integrally closed. Therefore, $\det(M)$ is $\pm$ a perfect square in $\Bbb Z[x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

For $n$ even , we have the same form for $N$. $P$ is not a square matrix, but
the determinant of $N$ is (except sign) the same as for the matrix
obtained after deleting last row and last column of $N$. From there, the steps from the case where $P$ is square apply.

Comment: If I had the patience to rewrite this proof, I'd rewrite it around the "lemma" that a symmetric matrix of size $2k$ has an absolute value of the determinant equal to a perfect square whenever it has a $k \times k$ zero principal submatrix.